# Obtaining tweets image urls with tweepy v2 on Twitter API v2

Tags: python, api, twitter, hyperlink, tweepy

what is an elegant way to access the urls of tweets pictures with tweepy v2?
Twitter released a v2 of their API and tweepy adjusted their python module to it (tweepy v2).

Lets say for example I have a dataframe of tweets created with tweepy, holding tweet id and so on. There is a row with this example tweet:
https://twitter.com/federalreserve/status/1501967052080394240

The picture is saved under a different url and the documentation on tweepy v2 does reveal if there is a way to access it.
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FNgO9vNXIAYy2LK?format=png&name=900x900

Reading thought the requests json obtained through `tweepy.Client(bearer_token, return_type = requests.Response)` did not hold the required links.

I am already using the following parameters in the client:

```
client.get_liked_tweets(user_id, 
                             tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'text', 'id', 'attachments', 'author_id', 'entities'], 
                             media_fields=['preview_image_url', 'url'],
                             user_fields=['username'],
                             expansions=['attachments.media_keys', 'author_id']
                             )
```

What would be a way to obtain or generate the link to the picture of the tweet? Preferably through tweepy v2 itself?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments of `get_liked_tweets` seem to be correct.

Have you looked in the `includes` dict at the root of the response?

The media fields are not in `data`, so you should have something like that:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "16_1211797899316740096"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "2244994945",
        "id": "1212092628029698048",
        "text": "[...]"
    },
    "includes": {
        "media": [
            {
                "media_key": "16_1211797899316740096",
                "preview_image_url": "[...]",
                "url": "[...]"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "2244994945",
                "username": "TwitterDev"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much. Short question: I've searched for this for hours. Is there a way to display the code this sorted? Because when I receive the json, it is always one long string and it is impossible to make out any keys.

Comment: @user18765140 You mean to pretty print the json dict in the console ? If so, you can do it with `print(json.dumps(json_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))` where `json_dict` is your json dictionnary. And if you have only the stringified json (but this is not supposed to be the case in your described case), you can load it before : `json_dict= json.loads(stringified_json)`.